# How to implement generic class spezialization in Dart

Tags: dart, generic-programming, specialization

In Dart we can use generic classes [class]. We can also specialize those classes [class]. However at runtime the specialization is not used. (In C++ this is called template programming)

Example: The following code will result in the output

Hallo world
How are you

```
class MyClass<T> {
  foo( print('Hallo world'); );
}

class MyClassInt implements MyClass<int> {
  @override
  foo( print('How are you'); );
}

main() {
  MyClass<int> a = Myclass<int>();
  MyClassInt b = MyClassInt();

  a.foo();
  b.foo();
}
```

How can the specialization (here type [int]) be done, that it is called at runtime, i.e.

```
main() {
  MyClass<int> a = Myclass<int>();

  a.foo();
}
```

should result in the outcome "How are you".

Comment: Dart generics don't support specialization.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by jamesdlin, Dart does not support specialization. But you can do something like this to make the illusion:

```
class MyClass<T> {
  factory MyClass() {
    if (T == int) {
      return MyClassInt() as MyClass<T>;
    } else {
      return MyClass._();
    }
  }

  // Hidden real constructor for MyClass
  MyClass._();

  void foo() {
    print('Hallo world');
  }
}

class MyClassInt implements MyClass<int> {
  @override
  void foo() {
    print('How are you');
  }
}

void main() {
  final a = MyClass<int>();
  final b = MyClassInt();
  final c = MyClass<String>();

  a.foo(); // How are you
  b.foo(); // How are you
  c.foo(); // Hallo world
}
```

Comment: Dear all, thanks for your answers. Using a switch strikes me awkward. I will have to look for an alternative design then. But, truely, in that case, allowing generic classes without specialization seems to be a pretty limited implementation that falls short of most of the benefits of the functionality.

Comment: It is not really a limitation I have experienced but maybe because I primarily are developing in Java and Dart, I am too "blind" to see the usefulness of this feature. Normally if you are making a generic class, you can code it so it works for all the types you need without additional classes. Alternative, you can write type specific classes and take the shared functionality from a shared common class by using `mixin`. And well, if there are a corner case, you can do as seen in my example for the few cases. But maybe you can come with an example which shows the need of this feature in Dart?